# How to set matching WCF service names in both Web.Config file and in the .svc ServiceHost

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, silverlight, servicehost

I have a silverlight application with a WCF service that has its .svc ServiceHost like below

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="App1.Web.GetData"
CodeBehind="GetData.svc.cs" %>
```

With the service tag defined as below under my web.config file's system.serviceModel section.

```
  <services>
        <service name="App1.Web.GetData">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="App1.GetData.customBinding0" contract="App1.GetData" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
```

In my development environment, a client can successfully connect to the service, but once deployed in production, i have to first modify the service name=**"App1.Web.GetData"** i.e remove "***Web***" such that itsservice name= **"App1.GetData"**, only then will the service be found by the client silverlight application.

But as you can abserve, that creates a mismatch between the ServiceHost name in the .svc file and the service name in the web.config file.

And then i read from the link below this quote in  **Carlos Figueira** reply.

> "So if you want the configuration on web.config to apply to your
>   service, you need to set as the "name" attribute of the 
>   element the fully-qualified name of the service, which is the exact
>   same name as is used in the "Service" attribute of the ServiceHost
>   directive in the .svc file."http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c7571eb-2a37-4325-b9d5-4dfa3228c9e7/content-type-applicationsoapxml-charsetutf8-was-not-supported-by-service-error?forum=wcf

And because my Service name in .svc and web.config files are un-matched in production unlike in dev environment, i get the error that i at the following link earlier. 
[Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+msbin1' was not the expected type 'text/xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608881/cannot-process-the-message-because-the-content-type-application-soapmsbin1-wa)

Comment: Can you post your production congfiguration ? To what kind of address would you like to expose the service ?

Comment: @RomEh, the only difference between my production config is that i have to change App1.Web.GetData to App1.GetData. Only then the service can be discovered but then again that creates a service name mismatch between the .svc and web.config files which results in an error i posted ealier at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608881/cannot-process-the-message-because-the-content-type-application-soapmsbin1-wa